# C# :Problem With Internationalization when setting the CultureInfo Class

Tags: visual-studio, internationalization, c#-3.0, globalization, cultureinfo

I am trying to implement an internationalization library. I created it and it was working fine but i have one problem.
 public static void SetCurrentLanguage(string language)
        {

```
        if (m_resourceManager == null)
        {   
            CultureInfo cultInfo = new CultureInfo(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

            m_resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager("Globalization", m_path, null);
        }
```

The above function is called twice with two different function. When it is called from first function we setCurrentLanguage(de-DE) and it works well.
but when we call the function second time it gives me the result in (en-EN) beacuse culture is not set second time due m_resourceManager is not null.

What i want that if i set first time cultureInfo class with de-DE language for second call also it should be set.

I am stuck at this point. Can anyone please help me with that ?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you rearrange the method to something like so?

```
public static void SetCurrentLanguage(string language) {

    CultureInfo cultInfo = new CultureInfo(language);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

    if (m_resourceManager == null)
    {   
        m_resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager("Globalization", m_path, null);
    }
}
```

So you just create the resource manager when it's null but still change the cultureinfo everytime the function is called.